# Home does not contain an export named Home

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I was working with `create-react-app` and came across this issue where I get an error:

> Home does not contain an export named Home.

Here's how I set up my `App.js` file:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Home } from './layouts/Home'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Hello
        <Home />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now in my `layouts` folder I have the `Home.js` file, which is setup like following:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p className="App-intro">
        Hello Man
      </p>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

As you can see, I am exporting the `Home` component. But I get an error in my console saying this:

[image]

What is going on?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are importing incorrectly. Here's the code you have to add:

```
import { Home } from './layouts/Home';
```

This is incorrect because you're exporting as the default export, not as a named export. Check this line:

```
export default Home;
```

You're exporting *as default*, not as a name. Thus, import `Home` like this:

```
import Home from './layouts/Home';
```

Notice there are no curly brackets. Further reading on [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: Or you could also do a named export. Ex.
export {Home};

Comment: @AbhinavSingi Yes, but it's convention and widely practiced to export a component as the default export of a module. Plus there are no other exports.

Comment: Yes, exactly @AndrewLi, we also follow the same practice :)

Comment: Awesome so multiple would be wrapped in curly brackets compared with singular as seen here.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Yes, if you have multiple exports, use named ones. Then import using that name as seen in the linked MDN documentation.

Comment: Oh man, thanks for this!  It was driving me nuts trying to figure out what I'd done wrong.  Talk about a persnckety programming language.  Yikes.

Is there a vs plugin that will automatically format js/tsx code to make it harder to make these mistakes?

Comment: I was able to fixed the warnings messages using `import * as Dash from 'react-native-dash'` from webpack. I suspect some aspect of [this implementation](https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-dash/blob/master/dist/index.js) has been deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

Use

```
import Home from './layouts/Home'
```

rather than

```
import { Home } from './layouts/Home'
```

Remove `{}` from Home

Comment: What else does this add to the existing answer?

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where you mixed up **default** exports and **named** exports.

When dealing with the `named` exports, if you try to import them you should use curly braces as below,

```
import { Home } from './layouts/Home'; // if the Home is a named export
```

In your case the Home was exported as a default one. This is the one that will get imported from the module, when you don’t specify a certain name of a certain piece of code. When you import, and omit the curly braces, it will look for the default export in the module you’re importing from. So your import should be,

```
import Home from './layouts/Home'; // if the Home is a default export
```

Some references to look :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export
- https://medium.com/@trekinbami/a-not-so-in-depth-explanation-of-es6-modules-import-and-export-13a80300f2f0

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error message (after upgrading to nextjs 9 some transpiled imports started giving this error). I managed to fix them using syntax like this:

```
import * as Home from './layouts/Home';
```

Answer (score 1):

We also can use

```
import { Home } from './layouts/Home';
```

using export keyword before class keyword.

```
export class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        ........
    }
}
```

For default

```
 import Home from './layouts/Home';
```

Default export class

```
 export default class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        ........
    }
 }
```

Both case don't need to write

```
export default Home;
```

after class.

Answer (score 0):

put `export { Home };` at the end of the Home.js file

Comment: in the question it state that he did ?

Answer (score 0):

Crazy as it may sound, i spent almost an hour to resolve a similar issue, restarted the localhost and it picked up by itself. Ridiculous but something restart fixes everything.
For me component in question was logout.

I imported like :
`import {Logout} from './components';`

with this define dint he Logout component
`export default Logout`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using create-next-app@14.1.0 it isn't your fault the build is just bugged. Reverting to create-next-app@14.0.4 will fix your problem

Answer (score -1):

You can use two ways to resolve this problem, first way that i think it as best way is replace importing segment of your code with bellow one:

```
import Home from './layouts/Home'
```

or export your component without default which is called named export like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <p className="App-intro">
          Hello Man
        </p>
        )
    }
} 

export {Home};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution:

- Go to your file Home.js
- Make sure you export your file like this in the end of the file:

```
export default Home;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good answer and should probably be downvoted. Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you post another anwer. Generally, you also shouldn't answer old questions with many other answers - unless you can add something new the other answers can't. Also include code.